# dependent data based on user selection from the drop-down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu, match, index-match

Here's the scenario for my problem,

I have a worksheet containing 2 sheets, one of them I tried to collect data on it. the other sheet I've tried to design it and make it easy to read.

I've tried to make a drop down list with related data based on user choose.
as an example
table of cars information, contain car type - colors - doors - buy or rent
this is the attributes name.
I want to to reflect in the first sheet as I said before, based on user choose of the car name from the dropdown list.

HELP please, Should I use Lookup or index-Match and HOW?

**Sheet 2**

[*Demo*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiJ2g.png)

Sheet 1

[*Demo*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkcFE.png)

Comment: have you try a Data Validation

Comment: yes, For dropdown list.

Comment: I would suggest to include some of your table to better understand your needs

Comment: You can use the new FILTER-function if you have Excel 365: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: Try also like this in your Sheet 1 in cell B6 and copy paste to last column =INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH($B$1,Sheet2!$B:$B,0),1)

Comment: Yes finally it's work!!! but can you please explain the formula?

Comment: Match() finds the position of an item in a list, then index() goes to the equivalent position in another list. Take it apart and test is the best way to understand.

Comment: @NorahAl-Kathiri can you tick mark Check to indicate it's close

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @12Rev79 I do not really understand what you mean by "tick mark Check to indicate it's close", but you seem to have confused OP into trying to mark the question as solved by editing it. That is not the way to do it. See my comment above.